# Execution exception InvocationTargetException: null when executing the tests in Linux/OSX environment using Play Framework Java

Tags: java, linux, macos, playframework, webservice-client

I am using Play Framework 2.4.x Java and as part of the requirement, I need to pull data from external services. To get this solved, I am using WSClient API. I did follow the steps as mentioned in the Play Framework document for testing Web Service Clients. : 
https://playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/JavaTestingWebServiceClients#Returning-files
The only difference is the I am returning xml instead of JSON. The tests works fine when I run under Windows environment, but the same tests are failing to execute on Linux or Mac environments. Do let me know if anyone of you have some solutions. Exception details are as below.

**Exception Details:**

```
 @6pc5ioc7f - Internal server error, for (GET) [/newsfeed.xml] ->

play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$$anon$1: Execution exception[[InvocationTargetException: null]]
    at play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$.throwableToUsefulException(HttpErrorHandler.scala:265) ~[play_2.11-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at play.api.http.DefaultHttpErrorHandler.onServerError(HttpErrorHandler.scala:191) ~[play_2.11-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$9$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:158) [play-netty-server_2.11-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$9$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:155) [play-netty-server_2.11-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:36) [scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
    at scala.util.Failure$$anonfun$recover$1.apply(Try.scala:216) [scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192) [scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
    at scala.util.Failure.recover(Try.scala:216) [scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$recover$1.apply(Future.scala:324) [scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$recover$1.apply(Future.scala:324) [scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:32) [scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
    at play.api.libs.iteratee.Execution$trampoline$.executeScheduled(Execution.scala:109) [play-iteratees_2.11-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at play.api.libs.iteratee.Execution$trampoline$.execute(Execution.scala:71) [play-iteratees_2.11-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.executeWithValue(Promise.scala:40) [scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryComplete(Promise.scala:248) [scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.Promise$class.complete(Promise.scala:55) [scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.complete(Promise.scala:153) [scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:23) [scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
    at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:40) [akka-actor_2.11-2.3.13.jar:na]
    at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:397) [akka-actor_2.11-2.3.13.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260) [scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339) [scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979) [scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107) [scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_72]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_72]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_72]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_72]
    at play.routing.RouterBuilderHelper$$anonfun$build$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$5.apply(RouterBuilderHelper.scala:66) ~[play-java_2.11-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at play.routing.RouterBuilderHelper$$anonfun$build$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$5.apply(RouterBuilderHelper.scala:62) ~[play-java_2.11-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at play.api.mvc.Action$.invokeBlock(Action.scala:533) ~[play_2.11-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at play.api.mvc.Action$.invokeBlock(Action.scala:530) ~[play_2.11-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at play.api.mvc.ActionBuilder$$anon$1.apply(Action.scala:493) ~[play_2.11-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$4$$anonfun$apply$5.apply(Action.scala:105) ~[play_2.11-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$4$$anonfun$apply$5.apply(Action.scala:105) ~[play_2.11-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at play.utils.Threads$.withContextClassLoader(Threads.scala:21) ~[play_2.11-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(Action.scala:104) ~[play_2.11-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(Action.scala:103) ~[play_2.11-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146) ~[scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
    at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Action.scala:103) ~[play_2.11-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Action.scala:96) ~[play_2.11-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$$anonfun$mapM$1.apply(Iteratee.scala:524) ~[play-iteratees_2.11-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$$anonfun$mapM$1.apply(Iteratee.scala:524) ~[play-iteratees_2.11-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$$anonfun$flatMapM$1.apply(Iteratee.scala:560) ~[play-iteratees_2.11-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$$anonfun$flatMapM$1.apply(Iteratee.scala:560) ~[play-iteratees_2.11-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$$anonfun$flatMap$1$$anonfun$apply$13.apply(Iteratee.scala:536) ~[play-iteratees_2.11-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$$anonfun$flatMap$1$$anonfun$apply$13.apply(Iteratee.scala:536) ~[play-iteratees_2.11-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24) [scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24) [scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
    ... 6 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at play.api.mvc.Results$Status.sendResource(Results.scala:451) ~[play_2.11-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at play.mvc.Results$StatusHeader.sendResource(Results.java:1390) ~[play_2.11-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at play.mvc.Results$StatusHeader.sendResource(Results.java:1379) ~[play_2.11-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at play.mvc.Results$StatusHeader.sendResource(Results.java:1357) ~[play_2.11-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at com.bovotech.subscription.provider.ScienceFeedTest.lambda$init$0(ScienceFeedTest.java:32) ~[test-classes/:na]
    ... 31 common frames omitted
[error] - application - Error
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"html"). Expected elements are <{}rss>
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.handleEvent(UnmarshallingContext.java:726) ~[na:1.8.0_72]
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportError(Loader.java:247) ~[na:1.8.0_72]
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportError(Loader.java:242) ~[na:1.8.0_72]
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportUnexpectedChildElement(Loader.java:109) ~[na:1.8.0_72]
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext$DefaultRootLoader.childElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:1131) ~[na:1.8.0_72]
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext._startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:556) ~[na:1.8.0_72]
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:538) ~[na:1.8.0_72]
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.SAXConnector.startElement(SAXConnector.java:153) ~[na:1.8.0_72]
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source) ~[xercesImpl-2.11.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.startElement(Unknown Source) ~[xercesImpl-2.11.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source) ~[xercesImpl-2.11.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDispatcher.scanRootElementHook(Unknown Source) ~[xercesImpl-2.11.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source) ~[xercesImpl-2.11.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source) ~[xercesImpl-2.11.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source) ~[xercesImpl-2.11.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source) ~[xercesImpl-2.11.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source) ~[xercesImpl-2.11.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source) ~[xercesImpl-2.11.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source) ~[xercesImpl-2.11.0.jar:na]
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:243) ~[na:1.8.0_72]
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:214) ~[na:1.8.0_72]
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:157) ~[na:1.8.0_72]
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:204) ~[na:1.8.0_72]
    at com.bovotech.subscription.provider.ScienceFeed.lambda$get$0(ScienceFeed.java:36) ~[classes/:na]
    at play.core.j.FPromiseHelper$$anonfun$map$1.apply(FPromiseHelper.scala:103) ~[play_2.11-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at scala.util.Success$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Try.scala:237) ~[scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192) ~[scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
    at scala.util.Success.map(Try.scala:237) ~[scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Future.scala:235) ~[scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Future.scala:235) ~[scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:32) ~[scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
    at play.core.j.HttpExecutionContext$$anon$2.run(HttpExecutionContext.scala:40) ~[play_2.11-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:40) ~[akka-actor_2.11-2.3.13.jar:na]
    at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:397) ~[akka-actor_2.11-2.3.13.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260) ~[scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339) ~[scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979) ~[scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107) ~[scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
```

**JUnit Test**

```
public class ScienceFeedTest {

WSClient wsClient;
Server server;

private ScienceFeed scienceFeed;


@Before
public void init() {

    Router router = new RoutingDsl()
            .GET("/newsfeed.xml").routeTo(() ->
                            ok().sendResource("sciencecloud.xml")
            )
            .build();

    server = Server.forRouter(router);
    wsClient = WS.newClient(server.httpPort());
    scienceFeed = new ScienceFeed();
    scienceFeed.setServiceEndPoint("/newsfeed.xml");
    scienceFeed.setClient(wsClient);
}

@Test
public void testThatCallingGetWillAlwaysReturnFeedResponse() throws JAXBException {
    F.Promise<FeedResponse> feedResponse = scienceFeed.get();
    Assert.assertNotNull(feedResponse);
    Assert.assertEquals(FeedResponse.class, feedResponse.get(10000).getClass());
}
```

Comment: actual error is javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"html"). Expected elements are <{}rss>

Comment: Yes, that is because from test, the file content is not being read. Attaching the code as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find the solution for this issue. When I use "**sbt test**" command I was able to reproduce the issue on Windows machine as well. The actual issue was, SendResource() was not able to load the xml file. That is because, the xml file was directly placed under test directory. I moved the xml file to **test/resource** directory and the issue got resolved

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your XML in the "newsfeed.xml" is wrong. Something like you need an "rss" tag but it is "html" tag in that place.

Please double check it - that this file has the same as on the windows.

Comment: XML files are same in all the environments.

Comment: You definitely have an error in the "ScienceFeed" class, and the error is because wrong XML:

"at com.bovotech.subscription.provider.ScienceFeed.lambda$get$0(ScienceFeed.java:36) ~[classes/:na]"

Could you add the code of "ScienceFeed" and the XML of "newsfeed.xml" ?

Comment: I was able to find the solution for this issue. When I use "sbt test" command I was able to reproduce the issue on Windows machine as well.  The actual issue was, SendResource() was not able to load the xml file. That is because, the xml file was directly placed under test directory. I moved the xml file to test/resource directory and the issue got resolved.